# Database does not updated on cell item changed

Tags: hibernate, primefaces

I want to make an update query on cell edit. I can edit existing cells but can't update it on the database, I can not make Hibernate queries on cell edit.So please help.

this is xhtml datatable

```
  <h:form id="view">
         <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>
        <p:panel header="View all" >
            <p:dataTable var="viewall" value="#{UserController.info}" id="viewalldata" editable="true" resizableColumns="true" style="margin-bottom:20px">



                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{UserController.onRowEdit}" update=":view:msgs" />
                <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{UserController.onRowCancel}" update=":view:msgs" />
               <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{UserController.onCellEdit}" update=":view:msgs" />

                <p:column headerText="Id">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{viewall.id}" /></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{viewall.id}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="UserName">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{viewall.userName}" /></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{viewall.userName}" style="width:100%" label=""/></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="FirstName">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{viewall.firstName}" /></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{viewall.firstName}" style="width:100%" label=""/></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                   <p:column headerText="LastName">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{viewall.lastName}" /></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{viewall.lastName}" style="width:100%" label=""/></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                   <p:column headerText="Password">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{viewall.password}" /></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{viewall.password}" style="width:100%" label=""/></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                  <p:column headerText="Email">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{viewall.email}" /></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{viewall.email}" style="width:100%" label=""/></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                 <p:column headerText="Phone">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{viewall.phone}" /></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{viewall.phone}" style="width:100%" label=""/></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:32px">
                    <p:rowEditor />
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
```

The outout is: [This is the view after read all data from MySQL database.][1]

this is my ManagedBean

```
@ManagedBean(name = "UserController")
@SessionScoped
public class UserController {

private User RegistrationUser;


public User getRegistrationUser() {
    return RegistrationUser;
}


public void setRegistrationUser(User RegistrationUser) {
    this.RegistrationUser = RegistrationUser;
}

public UserController() {
    this.RegistrationUser = new User();
}

public String register() {

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    session.save(RegistrationUser);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    System.out.println("Register User :" + this.RegistrationUser);
    String msg = "User Registered Successfully";
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, msg, msg));
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
    return "registration";
}

public String login() {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    String hql = "From User where userName='" + RegistrationUser.getUserName() + "' and password='" + RegistrationUser.getPassword() + "'";

    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    if (!query.list().isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("success log in");
    } else {
        System.out.println("not succeed at log in!");
    }
    session.beginTransaction();


    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    return null;
}

public List<User> getInfo() {
    return getUserInfo();
}

public List<User> getUserInfo() {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    String hql = "from User";
    Query q = sessionFactory.openSession().createQuery(hql);
    List<User> list = q.list();
    return list;
}

public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {


    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    String hql = "update User set userName=:userName,firstName=:firstName,lastName=:lastName,password=:password,email=:email,phone=:phone where id=:id";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("userName", RegistrationUser.getUserName());
    query.setParameter("firstName", RegistrationUser.getFirstName());
    query.setParameter("lastName", RegistrationUser.getLastName());
    query.setParameter("password", RegistrationUser.getPassword());
    query.setParameter("email", RegistrationUser.getEmail());
    query.setParameter("phone", RegistrationUser.getPhone());
    query.setParameter("id", RegistrationUser.getId());
    session.beginTransaction();


    query.executeUpdate();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Cell Edited", ((User) event.getObject()).getId().toString());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}

public void onRowCancel(RowEditEvent event) {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Cell Edit Cancelled", ((User) event.getObject()).getId().toString());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}

public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {


    Object oldValue = event.getOldValue().toString();
    Object newValue = event.getNewValue().toString();

    if (newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cell Changed", "Old: " + oldValue + ", New:" + newValue);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
}
```

}

This is User class

```
 public class User  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private Integer id;
 private String userName;
 private String password;
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private String email;
 private String phone;

public User() {
}


public User(String userName, String password) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.password = password;
}
public User(String userName, String password, String firstName, String     lastName, String email, String phone) {
   this.userName = userName;
   this.password = password;
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.lastName = lastName;
   this.email = email;
   this.phone = phone;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getUserName() {
    return this.userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return this.email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getPhone() {
    return this.phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
}
```

Comment: if the rowEdit events work, this question is not PrimeFaces related. And since all you post is xhtml and a minimal java code, no-one is able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onRowEdit method change the setting parameters like the followings-

```
query.setParameter("userName", ((User) event.getObject()).getUserName());
query.setParameter("firstName", ((User) event.getObject()).getFirstName());
```

... and so on